# Changing scale of one map sheet within map series in MPS Atlas?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, scale, esri-production-mapping

I am using MPS Atlas and have a large map series (almost 300 map sheets) with the Areas Of Interest defined by the polygons of a feature class with a 100 m buffer on each polygon. This works well for most of the map sheets. However, for 7 of the map sheets the scale needs to be larger (i.e. they need to be zoomed out further than the extent of the polygon).

How can I change this with out changing the extent for the rest of the map sheets?

I have tried making the map sheets I want to change "single" (i.e. not shared) but when I do this I cannot find an option to change or reset the scale.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I wish this was a possibility. The scale setting sets the same scale. It is my opion that when the scale was programmed they must have meant for it to apply to single sheets but did not implement.

Comment: I have used a method of picking a scale "in-between" my upper and lower needs.

Answer (score 1):

Set the scale bar to whatever interval you want it to be, then convert it to graphics. Ungroup the scale bar and then ungroup the line of labels for the End and Subdivision text.  Then create dynamic text and set the target to a field in a your Map Grid which is storing text for these values.  "ScaleBarEnd and ScaleBarSub" are the field names I created.  This way the scale bar stays at an even inch while the text for what it represents changes.